# Errorbars formatting in Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Using a macro in excel 2007 I want to display the following errorbars:

- No horizontal errorbar.
- Red dashed with 100 plus value vertical errorbar.

I can get everything I want except the color and I don't understand why. Below is the code.

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).HasErrorBars = True
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).ErrorBars
    .EndStyle = xlNoCap
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .Format.Line.Weight = 2
    .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineDash
End With
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlNone, Type:=xlFixedValue, Amount:=0
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, Include:=xlPlusValues, Type:=xlFixedValue, Amount:=100
```

Comment: what about the color? are you getting different color than expected? or no color at all?

Comment: Everything is solid black instead of red.

Comment: I suspect it is Blue not Black. Try RGB(0,0,255)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue too. But after toggling the visible state of the error bars, the color change worked for me. Give this a try:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).HasErrorBars = True
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).ErrorBars
    .EndStyle = xlNoCap
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Format.Line.Visible = False                 'ADDED          
    .Format.Line.Visible = True                  'ADDED
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)  'ADDED
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .Format.Line.Weight = 2
    .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineDash
End With
```

Comment: This is the solution, and this problem only affects Excel 2007 (not later versions).  Can't wait for Microsoft to stop supporting Office 2007...